Nested custom field types
I'm trying to nest custom field types. My precise use case is quite complex, so I will try to simplify the problem with a made-up example.
Let's say I create a custom field type named "timedate_field" which is basically the same as the "datetime_field", but the time and date field are inverted. That's easy, I implement the FieldType, FieldFormatter, and FieldWidget. So far so good, the custom field type is working and I can add it to my article content type.
Now, I want to create another custom field type named "period". That field type simply have to "timedate" fields in it. I do the same, implement the FieldType, FieldFormatter, and FieldWidget. I can add it to my article node, but the widget are not displayed.
When I list all the available field type, I can see "datetime", but not my custom "timedate" field. It's like if the field was not fully defined in "Form API" or something.
function period_field_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $form_element_types = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.element_info')->getDefinitions();
  $types = [];
  foreach ($form_element_types as $type => $definition) {
    $types[] = $type;
  }
  \Drupal::logger('period_field')->notice('Field types: <pre>' . print_r($types, TRUE) . '</pre>');
}

How can I create a custom field type, fully integrated into Drupal, so I can use it in another custom field type?
[EDIT]
While browsing Drupal 10.3 source code, I found:
/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Datetime/Element/Datetime.php
#[FormElement('datetime')]
class Datetime extends DateElementBase { ... }

Do I need to define a FormElement in order to be able to use my custom field type in another custom field type?

The only difference between case1 and case2 is that the field widget is not displayed, so you probably need to add more information about this detail. In your debugging attempts you are listing render/form elements, not field types. Do you have custom form elements defined in your module or are you using standard form elements?

Just to make it clear, first "scenario" is setting up a custom field type. I show that the field type actually works. Second scenario, I try to use that custom field type in ANOTHER custom field type (aka nested field type). I tried that multiple times, it never works. The custom field type doesn't get registered properly or something and it is not available at the field type level. But it's available at the content type level. I want to nest custom field types. How can I do that?

You can only nest field properties, not other field types. The widget can then recycle the logic of the form element for a property. If you have custom form elements.

I believe I found out how it works.
There are 2 similar field "concept" in Drupal. Element and Field.
Element: Basic field definition, that is used to build a form. They define what HTML elements are use in the field, but not how the field is saved in the database. Quite basic, low level. They are the only thing that can be used when writing the formElement method of a custom Field Type Widget.
Field: They are high level field definition, which define what Element to use, how to save the field data in the database, how to display them, etc. They are the thing that are use when adding field to an entity, such as a Node, Media, User, etc.
Where the confusion comes is that most Element defined in Drupal core also have a corresponding Field associated with it, and they usually share the same name.
One exception I have found is "telephone":

The Element for telephone is "tel".
The Field for telephone is "telephone".

You can add a "#type" => "tel" to a custom field type (since it's a primitive Element), but you can't add a "#type" => "telephone" (because "telephone" is a Field, and Field can't be nested in other Field).
If you think I'm wrong, please show me a working example. I would be quite please to be able to nest Fields.

Yes, this is for field widgets (one field type can have multiple widgets), field formatters use core or custom render elements and the field type defines properties using core or custom data types.
